# How to create a mobile version?

Tags: css, html, mobile

I was wondering if someone can help me with "How to create a mobile version" from any site?

First steps?

I was using "responsive css style" to resize the website to a "mobile resolution" but I thinking in others sites using **"m.mysite.com"** and I dont know how to make it.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a broad question and there are some approaches. Mine is to use **media queries** in my css files for the mobile version. If it's a new project, consider using a responsive framework, such as **Bootstrap**. (You can simply google it for more details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Bootstrap 3 grid system. No matter on what device or resolution your website is viewed, if used correctly, it will resize accordingly. 
Just go to http://getbootstrap.com and you'll find all the information and examples there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for creating **m.yoursite.com** for mobile users you should read [this post](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-the-m-subdomain-for-mobile-websites)
You have to create a **Subdomain for your Mobile Users** as described here.